# 2 Classes implements same Interface --> Throw ClassCastException

Tags: java, interface, classloader, classcastexception

I have 2 classes which implements the same interface called IProcess.

IProcess.java

```
    package org.XXX.module.workflow.bo.interfaces;

    public interface IProcess extends IMasterObject {

    INode getCurrentNode();
    INode getPreviousNode();
    long getLastChange();
    IWorkflow getWorkflow();
}
```

First Class

```
package org.XXX.module.workflow.database.bo.impl;

import org.XXX.module.workflow.bo.interfaces.INode;
import org.XXX.module.workflow.bo.interfaces.IProcess;
import org.XXX.module.workflow.bo.interfaces.IWorkflow;
import org.XXX.module.workflow.database.jdbc.entity.ProcessEntity;

public class ProcessEntityWrapper implements IProcess {

private String id;
private INode currentNode;
private INode previousNode;
private long lastChange;
private IWorkflow workflow;

public ProcessEntityWrapper(ProcessEntity entity) {
    this.id = entity.getId();
    this.lastChange = entity.getLastChange();
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public INode getCurrentNode() {
    return currentNode;
}

@Override
public INode getPreviousNode() {
    return previousNode;
}

@Override
public long getLastChange() {
    return lastChange;
}

@Override
public IWorkflow getWorkflow() {
    return workflow;
}

/**
 * @param currentNode the currentNode to set
 */
public void setCurrentNode(INode currentNode) {
    this.currentNode = currentNode;
}

/**
 * @param prevoiusNode the prevoiusNode to set
 */
public void setPreviousNode(INode previousNode) {
    this.previousNode = previousNode;
}

/**
 * @param workflow the workflow to set
 */
public void setWorkflow(IWorkflow workflow) {
    this.workflow = workflow;
}
```

}

Second Class:

```
package org.XXX.module.workflow.bo.impl;

import org.XXX.module.workflow.bo.interfaces.INode;
import org.XXX.module.workflow.bo.interfaces.IProcess;
import org.XXX.module.workflow.bo.interfaces.IWorkflow;

public class Process implements IProcess {

public Process(String id, INode currentNode, INode previousNode,
        long lastChange, IWorkflow workflow) {
    this.id = id;
    this.currentNode = currentNode;
    this.previousNode = previousNode;
    this.lastChange = lastChange;
    this.workflow = workflow;
}

private String id;
private INode currentNode;
private INode previousNode;
private long lastChange;
private IWorkflow workflow;

@Override
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public INode getCurrentNode() {
    return currentNode;
}

@Override
public INode getPreviousNode() {
    return previousNode;
}

@Override
public long getLastChange() {
    return lastChange;
}

@Override
public IWorkflow getWorkflow() {
    return workflow;
}

/**
 * @param currentNode the currentNode to set
 */
public void setCurrentNode(INode currentNode) {
    this.currentNode = currentNode;
}

/**
 * @param previousNode the previousNode to set
 */
public void setPreviousNode(INode previousNode) {
    this.previousNode = previousNode;
}

/**
 * @param lastChange the lastChange to set
 */
public void setLastChange(long lastChange) {
    this.lastChange = lastChange;
}

}
```

Part, which throw the ClassCastException:

```
@Override
public void route(IProcess process, INode nextNode) {
    if(initializedClient == null) {
        return;
    }
    Process processImpl = (Process) process;
    processImpl.setPreviousNode(process.getCurrentNode());
    processImpl.setCurrentNode(nextNode);
    dataAccess.updateProcess(processImpl);
}
```

**process** is a ProcessEntityWrapper -Object and **processImpl** is a **Process** Object

I don't know, why the specific code throws the **ClassCastException**. Can anybody help me, please?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public void updateProcess(IProcess process) {
    TypedQuery<ProcessEntity> q = em.createQuery(WorkflowAccessProperties.SELECT_PROCESSES_BY_ID,ProcessEntity.class);
    q.setParameter("id", process.getId());
    ProcessEntity entity = (ProcessEntity) q.getSingleResult();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    entity.setLastChange(System.currentTimeMillis());

    String previousId = null;

    if(process.getPreviousNode() != null) {
        previousId = process.getPreviousNode().getId();
    }

    entity.setPreviousNodeId(previousId);
    entity.setCurrentNodeId(process.getCurrentNode().getId());
    em.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

Comment: `ProcessEntityWrapper` is not a `Process`. I'm not really sure why you don't understand this except that you need to go back to the basics.

Comment: They may share the same interface, but that does not mean that you're able to switch between them if you like. Check if `process` is of type `Process` before casting it: `if (process instanceof Process) { /* cast *}/`.

Comment: ok...i'm sorry but i don't understand the basics of Interfaces. i thougt, if any classes implements the same interfaces, i would be possible to cast implementations to each other. My use case: i have to jar files, which set the same interface IProcess (located in same package nature in both JAR's). i set specific values in first "jar" and modify (after cast) the object in 2. jar file. Please excuse my bad english :)

Comment: @ruby85 You can cast to the interface type: `(IProcess) processEntityWrapperInstance;`, but not between different implementations of that interface.

Comment: @Tom ...i understand but the interfaces only declare Only-Read methods...how can i update different values of the objects, if i don't use an implementation which provide write access to "private" members? *EDIT* also i want to use the same object between the jars. i won't make a copy of the object

Answer (score 2):

Although `ProcessEntityWrapper` and `Process` implements the same interface they don't extend from each other.

They are different classes just implementing the same interface.

Any class can implement an interface. This doesn't mean they can be converted to eachother.

Example: A cow and a bird can implement the same interface but you can't convert a cow to a bird just because they implement the same interface.

```
public interface Speakable(){
   public String speak();
}

public class Cow implements Speakable(){
   public String speak(){
      return "moooo";
   }
}

public class Bird implements Speakable(){
   public String speak(){
      return "vik vik";
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer my question. i comprehend your example. But, how can i resolve my problem? i would communicate between 2 jar files which don't know from each other. i thought, if every jar file implements the same interface i can communicate with each other...

Comment: Can you post dataAccess.updateProcess() method's code?

Comment: Please have a Look at my start post